# What is the word that means "not saying anything bad in any way about someone"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

I have this sentence where I used the word **infringement**, and I think I'm exaggerating things a bit by choosing it. Moreover, I want it to mean: ***not saying anything bad in any way about someone***, ***not speaking of them badly***.

The sentence:

> How do I explain my stance without infringement his family and without
>   putting myself in an awkward position in front of him?

So, is there a suitable word to put it instead of **infringement**?

Also, about the word **stance**, does it mean **position**? And, does it fit in that sentence?

Comment: Using "infringement" here isn't 'exaggerating things a bit', it's just wrong. It doesn't fit in the sentence grammatically and it doesn't have the meaning you suggest.

Comment: @MichaelKay Consider it infringing, so it would be grammatically correct.

Comment: @TasneemZh *in·fringe* (v) - actively break the terms of (a law, agreement, etc.).

Comment: Quite. You can infringe a law or regulation, you can't infringe a family.

Comment: The sentence construction just doesn’t sound natural, regardless of the word you choose. Perhaps you want something like “without insulting...” or “without impugning his family’s pride/honor.”

Comment: @MichaelKay You can certainly infringe *upon* someone, in the sense of “to encroach.”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your question asks for a term that means the opposite of "infringing" or "disparaging", the word I would recommend is "tact."

> [tact](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tact)
>
> a keen sense of what to do or say in order to maintain good relations with others or avoid offense
>
> *The peace talks required great tact on the part of both leaders.*

The word "tact" is often used in the form of an adjective ("tactful") or an adverb ("tactfully"). One might also say that something must be said "with tact." The sentence you provided could then become:

> How do I explain my stance with tact, so that I do not offend his family or put myself in an awkward position with him?

Comment: The reconstruction of my sentence that you made with the words **tact** and **offend** is perfect. That's why I chose this answer as the best one.

Answer (score 14):

It should be *infringing* and it’s not clear to me what it could mean in this example. Your usage of *stance* seems correct here.

You could consider *disparaging*:

> [disparage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/disparage)
>   transitive verb
>   If you disparage someone or something, you speak about them in a way which shows that you do not have a good opinion of them.
>   [formal]
>   *...Larkin's tendency to disparage literature.*
>   (Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 11):

If the context is that you're trying not to say something bad about the family, you could possibly use *casting apsersions*?

> [cast aspersions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast%20aspersions)
>   to say harsh critical things about someone or someone's character
>   [formal]
>   *...He tried to discuss his political opponents respectfully, without casting aspersions.*
>   (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

So in your case, that would be

> How do I explain my stance without **casting aspersions on** his family and without putting myself in an awkward position in front of him?

Comment: If I write that expression in my story, would the native English readers understand it? Or should I clarify what **cast aspersions** means because it is rare as I last checked?

Comment: it might be rare but it isn't obsolete, do not be afraid of expanding your or others vocabulary, with good words. if we only ever use words 100% of our audience understand we will end up writing peter and jane stories, as nobody will ever learn any new words. (https://mylearningkid.net/product/peter-and-jane-keywords-box-set-36-books/)

Comment: I went with the Merriam-Webster definition as I wasn't sure how common the usage is elsewhere, but in Ireland and the UK it wouldn't be that rare.

Comment: Cast aspersions is very good here. It is very used across all varieties of English. It is not rare. It is an idiomatic expression.

Comment: I think "disparaging" is closer to the meaning the OP wants to convey. To my mind "casting aspersions" is not directly saying something bad about someone, rather it is hinting that there might be bad things that could be said.

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, you can both use *stance* and *position*.

Instead of ***infringement*** (which should be `without infringing` in your sentence, by the way) I'd use ***offending***.

> How do I explain my stance without **offending** his family and without putting myself in an awkward position in front of him?

<sub>(Native German Speaker)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by *bad*—it can be taken in many different ways. It could be an insult, a criticism, a social faux pas, and so on.

But I can think of a general word to use that would cover almost all meanings of *bad*:

> How do I explain my stance without **upsetting** his family and without putting myself in an awkward position in front of him?

You can be **upset** in any number of ways—from mild displeasure or annoyance all the way to insult and anger.

---

As for **stance**, I would say that it means **viewpoint** or **belief** here. (It could be equated with one sense of *position*, but that word has other senses that don't make it quite as relevant.)

**Stance** is perfectly understandable in this sentence.

Comment: I don't think "upsetting" is quite the meaning the OP wanted to convey. Saying bad things about someone is "disparaging" them; upsetting them is a possible consequence of disparaging them, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelKay But how do you know what the question intended to convey? It's not clear. You can *upset* someone because you've called them a name—or because you've spilled a secret. Both of those things are *bad* things to say in a particular  context. *Don't say that. That would not be good. It would be bad.* The original question didn't defined *bad* in any way at all. So, any meaning that we ascribe to it is simply an assumption.

Answer (score 7):

You may be thinking of impugning, it has an archaic meaning "to assault with words".

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion. Your answer could use a little more explanation though. How would "impugning" fit into the example sentence? What is the modern meaning?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impugn doesn't put it as archaic "to assail by words or arguments : oppose or attack as false or lacking integrity".  I think in OP's case it would be "without impugning the character of his family".  I think it would be a bit stiff though.  (but a lot of suggestions here are)

Answer (score 3):

Try **diplomatic** (adjective) or **diplomatically** (adverb).

> [diplomatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diplomatic)
>
> 2. Exhibiting diplomacy; exercising tact or courtesy; using discussion to avoid hard feelings, fights or arguments.

Used like this:

> How do I explain my stance **diplomatically**?

Comment: Isn't it a bit too formal for a family issue?

Comment: One does not need to be a diplomat to be diplomatic.  Indeed, I have heard it used among people's friends or family.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you want to do it "without **badmouthing** his family".

Here's a definition of the verb "badmouth":

> to say bad things about (someone or something) : to criticize (someone or something)
>   <sub>[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bad-mouth)</sub>

The word is slightly informal and can be either written as a single word or hyphenated ("bad-mouth").